# Can I leave away an association class for many to many relations?

Tags: uml, associations, class-diagram

Just a simple question: I'm working on a class diagram for a dynamic web site for my internship. I have an association between two classes (client and article), the relation is many to many.

Normally I have to add an association class between them, but I don't want to because the client can only read the article's writing on the web page, and he cannot post. Is it correct if I don't draw the association class on the diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to add association class only due to many to many relationship. The association class is needed when you have an association that at the same time is also a class, i.e. has some properties on its own.

You can use simple association with any multiplicity on any of the ends including having `*` on both ends.